# LESS Variables as parametric mixins

Tags: css, variables, less, mixins, opentype

I'm relatively new to `LESS` and I'm trying to figure out a way to have simple code for activating and deactivating OpenType features. I understand what a variable and a parametric mixin is but am not sure how to put them together, if possible.
 Other suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
/*Variables for enabling and disabling feature*/
@on: 1;
@off: 0;

/*Turn on feature*/
.liga (@on){
    -moz-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    -ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    -o-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    -webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    font-feature-settings:"liga" 1;
}

/*Turn off feature*/
.liga (@off){
    -moz-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    -ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    -o-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    -webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    font-feature-settings:"liga" 0;
}

/*Sample use*/
p{
    .liga(@on);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `when` conditions in less like this:

```
@onoff:1;
.liga(@onoff) when (@onoff = 1) {
    -moz-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    -ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    -o-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    -webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    font-feature-settings:"liga" 1;
}

.liga(@onoff) when (@onoff = 0) {
    -moz-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    -ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    -o-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    -webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    font-feature-settings:"liga" 0;
}


p{
    .liga(@onoff);
}
```

or you can try to create a unique function and pass value inside it like this:

```
.liga(@value){
        -moz-font-feature-settings:"liga" @value; 
        -ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" @value; 
        -o-font-feature-settings:"liga" @value; 
        -webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" @value; 
        font-feature-settings:"liga" @value;
    }

p{
    .liga(1); //or .liga(0); or .liga(@on); or .liga(@off);
}
```

Comment: In this case, I would go with the second and pass the value in.

Comment: yes I have showed two case of uses... but in this case I agree with you, second is better for OP scope @ScottS

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `when` conditions by just replacing the parameters of the parametric mixins with the actual expected values of `1` or `0`.

```
/*Variables for enabling and disabling feature*/
@on: 1;
@off: 0;

/*Turn on feature*/
.liga (1){ /*<-------CHANGED HERE */
    -moz-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    -ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    -o-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    -webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1; 
    font-feature-settings:"liga" 1;
}

/*Turn off feature*/
.liga (0){ /*<-------CHANGED HERE */
    -moz-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    -ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    -o-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    -webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0; 
    font-feature-settings:"liga" 0;
}

/*Sample use*/
p{
    .liga(@on);
}
```

Comment: seems to me the 1 or 0 can be passed directly into the mixin, so instead of having 2, 1 should be enough. .liga(@val) then -moz-font-feature-settings:"liga" @val;

Comment: @Huangism: yes, that was Alessandro Minoccheri's second answer (which I do like), but I was just offering another possibility here.

Comment: It's another different way to solve the problem, I like to use variable into argument function to make that more dynamic, but is only an opinion @Huangism